# Dynamic index naming with class name

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm creating a framework for spring-data-elasticsearch as a practice project. 
My question is about the @Document tag that will create the index based on the name provided in indexName parameter of annotation.

However, I'm thinking is it possible to make it dynamic! In most of my usecases, the index name will match the class name. All my index classes will extend a abstract class which has generic implementation for all the and specific implementations needs to be done in the entity class.

This means, I have to maintain the @Document annotation for every entity. But since all the entities will extend a particular abstract class, is it possible to annotate the abstract class and somehow tell spring to use the class name as index name.

```
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;

@Document(indexName = "BaseClassName OR something like Animal.getName" /*And other index properties of-course*/)
abstract class Animal {
String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public abstract String makeSomeNoise();
}
```

All the concrete class that extends the Animals will be indexed in Elasticserch.

```
abstract class TwoLeggedAnimals extends Animal {}

abstract class FourLeggedAnimals extends Animal {}
```

The above two are just the grouping classes. For the sake of the example

```
class Duck extends TwoLeggedAnimals {
public Duck() {
    this.name = Duck.class.getSimpleName();
}
@Override
public String makeSomeNoise() {
    return "quack";
}
}
```

Class Duck extends TwoLeggedAnimals which in turn extends the "Animals" class and thus, Duck qualifies for index creation.
The same explanation for Horse class

```
class Horse extends FourLeggedAnimals {
Horse() {
    this.name = Horse.class.getSimpleName();
}

@Override
public String makeSomeNoise() {
    return "neigh";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not write what your specific problem or error is and what ES version you are using.

You can put the `@Document` annotation with the index name on an abstract baseclass and then use a derived class to store your entites into the index without adding some annotation on your derived class; this works with no problems.

But you **cannot** store different types (like `TwoLeggedAnimals` and `FourLeggedAnimals`) in the same index since Elasticsearch 6.0 (see [ES 6.0 breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/breaking-changes-6.0.html)). Your program will work as long as you are using one type, as soon as you try to store the second type, you will get

> Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=Rejecting mapping update to [animals] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [twoleggedanimal, fourleggedanimal]]

The last 5.x version 5.6 had support until 2019-03-11 ([Elastic end of life dates](https://www.elastic.co/support/eol)), so that's not supported anymore.

So, as it is not possible to store more than one type in an index, you will have to rethink your classes and how you store them - please check [ES removal of types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html) as well, if the alternatives outlined there might help you.

Comment: The problem is with defining multiple indexes and not the types. So, in the above example I need to create index with Horse and Duck, without adding any annotation on Horse or Duck class.

Comment: sorry, I then misunderstood you. There are two issues for the dynamic index name resolution https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-387 and https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-456 as well as a pull request https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/221 which alas does not meet the necessary contribution conventions so it was not merged up to now.